# Viber сообщества. Отправка сообщений

Tags: php, laravel, viber

Есть необходимость автоматизировать для себя постинг записей на сайте, в группу вк, телеграмм ... и вайбер. И вот с вайбером возникли проблемы.

Что я пытаюсь реализовать? На сайте пишется текст сообщения и оно рассылается по соцсетям и месседжерам, включая сообщество в вайбере.

В вайбере вместо публичных страниц теперь доступны [Сообщества](https://support.viber.com/customer/ru/portal/articles/2915591-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2-viber#create-a-community).

Вообще, честно признаться, не совсем понимаю логику работы. С телеграмом всё просто. А тут что-то странное. Документация забита тем, как создавать бота. Но... зачем мне подписываться на какие-то события, чтобы просто отправить сообщение. И нет ничего про Сообщества. В общем, как тут быть? Подскажите, пожалуйста.